# How to get detailed logs when docker swarm deploy proccess is going?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm

[image]

I want to make a faster deployment process than before. Always too much time spent in this step.

But I can't find any way to see detailed docker logs such as Downloading, Pulling Images, Starting Containers, ... etc. I want to see it in the machine; I want to debug it. How to check this?

Answer (score 1):

These will be in various places.

`docker events` [will show you each action the scheduler takes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/), and any actions on the node you've run that command on. You'll need to run this on all potential nodes while creating/updating a service to get a full accounting of manager and worker events.

On the node that's been assigned a task to create a container, the [docker debug flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/) may give you more insight.